# Get another class from LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I am a little weak in LINQ to SQL so will try to explain my problem.

I have a method as follows (simplified to explain it better):

```
public static List<ic_ProductData> GetCompleteSimilarProductsWithApplyButton(InfoChoiceAdminDataContext db)
{

    var products = (from
                        p in db.ic_ProductDatas
                    join proddef in db.ic_ProductDefs on p.ProductDefId equals proddef.ProductDefId

                    select p
                        ).ToList();

    return products;
}
```

`ic_ProductData` and `ic_ProductDefs` are tables in my database

The `ic_ProductData` class contains a manually created property as:

```
public ic_ProductDef RelatedProductDef { get; set; }
```

I want to modify the above LINQ to SQL query so that I can populate this property.

Please note I do not want another call to the database.

Also there are a lot of properties in `ic_ProductData` so I want to avoid mapping each and every property

Something to the effect of the following (obviously the below is wrong):

```
public static List<ic_ProductData> GetCompleteSimilarProductsWithApplyButton(InfoChoiceAdminDataContext db)
{

    var products = (from
                        p in db.ic_ProductDatas
                    join proddef in db.ic_ProductDefs on p.ProductDefId equals proddef.ProductDefId
                    //trying to change here
                    select new ic_ProductData
                    {
                        //do something with p here so that all the properties of new object gets filled
                        // avoid mapping of properties here
                        RelatedProductDef = proddef
                    }
                        ).ToList();

    return products;
}
```

With my limited knowledge I am stuck here.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var query = (from p in db.ic_ProductDatas
                join proddef in db.ic_ProductDefs on p.ProductDefId equals proddef.ProductDefId
                select new 
                {
                    ProductData = p,
                    Def = proddef
                }).ToList();

List<ic_ProductData> products = new List<ic_ProductData>();
foreach( var product in query)
{
  product.ProductData.RelatedProductDef = product.Def;
  products.Add(product);
}
```

Basicly, you first need to do the one query to the database, this returns an anonymous type containing both your product and its Def.
Finally, you loop (in memory, no db-calls!) over these, creating your final objects with their `RelatedProductDef` properties populated.

Comment: `.ToList()` is unnecessary as the statement returns an `System.Linq.IQueryable<>` which can be used in the foreach loop instead

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy it is indeed unnecessary, I do find its impact (in performance) to be minimal however.

Comment: @Tom Wuyts This seems to be a good solution. Will give it a shot! Will update you on this soon. Up vote from me.